# store state of member variable in angular 2 class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, 2-way-object-databinding, es6-class

```
export class RSDLeadsComponent implements OnInit{
    templateModel:RSDLeads  = {
        "excludedRealStateDomains": [{"domain":""}],
        "leadAllocationConfigNotEditables": [{"attributeName":""}]
    };
    oldResponse:any;
    constructor(private lambdaService:LambdaService, @Inject(APP_CONFIG)private config:IAppConfig ){};
    ngOnInit():void{
        this.getFormData();
    };
    getFormData():void{
        let getPayload = {
            "pageId": "DomainLeads",
            "operationType": "view"
        };
        this.lambdaService.getResponse('LAConfigLambda', getPayload).then((data:any) => {
            const tempData = data;
            this.templateModel.excludedRealStateDomains = data.excludedRealStateDomains;     
            this.oldResponse = tempData.excludedRealStateDomains;
        });
    };
    save(model: RSDLeads, isValid: boolean):void{
        console.log("oldResponse",this.oldResponse);//oldResponse [Object, Object, Object]

    console.log("templateModel",this.templateModel.excludedRealStateDomains);//templateModel [Object, Object, Object]
    }
}
```

I return a promise from service lamdaService where i assign data from DB to template/member variable templateModel which gets modified though form in template.html. I want initial/old response to compare it with modified but i am not achieve it, as i've initiated new variable old response which gets updated with form and i get same result for both console.log in save function

Answer (score 0):

a deep copy of object worked for me

this.oldResponse =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.excludedRealStateDomains))